# How do you handle pthread_mutex_unlock failures?

Tags: pthreads

Assuming a thread successfully calls `pthread_mutex_lock`, is it still possible that a call to `pthread_mutex_unlock` in that same thread will fail? If so, can you actually do something about it besides abort the thread?

```
if(pthread_mutex_lock(&m) == 0)
{
   // got the lock, let's do some work

   if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&m) != 0) // can this really fail?
   {
      // ok, we have a lock but can't unlock it?
   }
}
```

From [this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_unlock.html), possible errors for `pthread_mutex_unlock()` are:

> [EINVAL]
>       The value specified by mutex does not refer to an initialised
>   mutex object.

If the lock succeeded then this is unlikely to fail.

> [EAGAIN]
>       The mutex could not be acquired because the maximum number of
>   recursive locks for mutex has been exceeded.

Really? For unlock?

> The pthread_mutex_unlock() function may fail if:
>
> [EPERM]
>       The current thread does not own the mutex.

Again, if lock succeeded then this also should not occur.

So, my thoughts are if there is a successful lock then in this situation unlock should never fail making the error check and subsequent handling code pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page for pthread_mutex_unlock:

```
The pthread_mutex_unlock() function may fail if:

EPERM
The current thread does not own the mutex.

These functions shall not return an error code of [EINTR].
```

If you believe the man page, it would seem that your error case cannot happen.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much my thought as well. I updated the question to hopefully make it more clear why I'm asking. I want to hold out to see if I can get any other input before I accept an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Well before you cry "victory". I ended up on this page looking for a reason why one of my programs failed on a `pthread_mutex_unlock` (on HP-UX, not Linux).

```
if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex) != 0)
   throw YpException("unlock %s failed: %s", what.c_str(), strerror(errno));
```

This failed on me, after many million happy executions. 
errno was `EINTR`, although I just now found out that I should not be checking errno, but rather the return value. But nevertheless, the return value was NOT 0. And I can mathematically prove that at that spot I do own a valid lock.

So let's just say your theory is under stress, although more research is required ;-)

Comment: Awesome! or perhaps not awesome. :-) This is exactly the kind of feedback I'm looking for. Are you able to reproduce this error or was it a one time thing? It would be interesting to know what the actual return value was since `pthread_mutex_unlock()` isn't supposed to return `EINTR`, in `errno` or otherwise.

Comment: i've not been able to reproduce it. I fixed my logging to show the actual return value, instead of errno. Next time it happens (I hope not) I will let you know what exactly it was ;-)

Comment: Little update: i've been having spurious occurrences of failed unlocks, return value == 1, meaning "Not owner". This turned out to be a very subtle bug.
I wrap all my locks in objects (destructor unlocks). This is handy as the lock ends automatically together with the object's scope.
In this function I was calling thread_exit(). Man page says you can't use automatic variables after thread_exit(). Which is exactly what my lock-wrapping object's destructor was doing (implicitly called AFTER thread_exit).

Comment: Looking at the man page for `pthread_mutex_lock`, it says "If successful, the pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock() functions shall return zero; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error." I don't think you can rely on it setting `errno` in general.